# Aframe fire raycaster on drop event

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to drop an object into a 3D scene from a React UI.

I can capture the drop data/ position etc, I'm now trying to use this in a RayCaster to determine what 3D entity has been dropped onto.

```
const handleDragStop = (e) => {
    console.log(e)

    const scene = document.getElementById('scene');
    const raycaster:any = scene.getAttribute("raycaster");
    const camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;

    console.log(raycaster)
    console.log(AFRAME.scenes[0])

    const mouse = new window.THREE.Vector2();
    mouse.x = ( e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( e.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
    console.log(intersects)
};
```

The Aframe version of RayCaster does not seem to to have the raycaster.setFromCamera() function, it's not recognised as a function.

How do I fire a raycaster from a drop event?

EDIT

I can get it working with a new Raycaster

```
const raycaster = new window.THREE.Raycaster();
```

The new question is, how do I get this raycaster to use the same objects as the existing one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the THREE raycaster you have to do the following on an entity with the raycaster component:

```
entityEl.components.raycaster.raycaster.setFromCamera(..);
```

Make sure you are in the [latest A-Frame release](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/releases)